# Arithmetic genus of divisors on cubic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a question from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry (Chapter V.4). It asks to show that for any divisor $D$ of degree $d$ on a smooth cubic surface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ the following inequality is satisfied:
$$
p_a(D) \leq
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{6}(d-1)(d-2) & d\equiv 1,2\mbox{ (mod $3$)}\\
\frac{1}{6}(d-1)(d-2) + \frac{2}{3} & d\equiv 0\mbox{ (mod $3$)}
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $p_a(D)$ is the arithmetic genus of $D$ defined for an arbitrary divisor $D$ by the adjunction formula ($2p_a(D) - 2 = D\cdot (D+K)$).

Now, the adjunction formula has $p_a(D) = 1 + \frac{D^2 + D\cdot K}{2}$ and I can determine $D\cdot K$ as follows. Regarding $X$ as the blow up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at 6 points, we have $D \equiv_{\text{lin}} aH - \sum b_iE_i$ for some $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ (where $H$ is the pullback of a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and the $E_i$ are the exceptional divisors). Then $K \equiv -3H + \sum E_i$ which means $D\cdot K = -3a + \sum b_i$. But $3H - \sum E_i = -K$ is the new hyperplane divisor of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ so $D\cdot K = -d$.

So now we have $p_a(D) = 1 - \frac{d}{2} + \frac{D^2}{2}$. To complete this, I clearly need to compare $D^2$ and $d$. Working backwards, it's not hard to see that what I need is
$$
D^2 \leq \left\{\begin{array}{cl}\frac{d^2 - 4}{3} & d\equiv 1,2\mbox{ (mod $3$)}\\
\frac{d^2}{3} & d\equiv 0\mbox{ (mod $3$)}
\end{array}\right.
$$
but I can't see how to get this. All I can say is that $D^2 = a^2 - \sum b_i^2$ and 
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
d^2 & = & (3a - \sum b_i)^2 = 9a^2 + (\sum b_i)^2 - 6a\sum b_i\\
& = & 9a^2 + (\sum b_i)^2 - 6a(3a-d)\\
& \leq & -9a^2 + 6\sum b_i^2 + 6ad \mbox{ (because $(\sum b_i)^2 \leq 6\sum b_i^2$ by Schwarz's inequality)}\\
& = & -6D^2 - 3a^2 + 6ad\\
& = & -6D^2 - 3(a-d)^2 - 3d^2\\
& \leq & -6D^2 - 3d^2
\end{array}
$$
but this gives me $D^2 \leq -\frac{2}{3}d^2$ which seems to be way stronger than what I want (and thus probably not true). I just can't see what I might have done wrong and what is the correct way to compare $D^2$ and $d$. Can anyone see it?